# how to set picturebox image location from zip without extrat?

Tags: c#, zip

I want to set picture box from zip file without extract zip.
my code:

```
ZipFile zip = new ZipFile("data.zip");
using (Stream s = zip["p3.png"].OpenReader())
{
    picturebox.ImageLocation = s.ToString();
}
```

Picture Box Show error image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should use Bitmap. Correct Code:

```
ZipFile zip = new ZipFile("data.zip");
using (Stream s = zip["p3.png"].OpenReader())
{
    Bitmap bitmap= new Bitmap(s);
    PictureBox picturebox.Image = bitmap;
}
```