# C# load an image to picture box from .pak archive

Tags: c#, winforms, archive

I've been trying to figure out how to load an image to picture box from .pak archive file?

Basically I have a WinForms app and I have an image in .pak file and I want using C# code to load the image to picture box from the .pak archive.

Thanks everyone for help, every idea is appreciated.

Comment: Try renaming it to .zip and unzip the .pak, if that works just use the Zip libraries provided by the framework. If that doesnt work, try to find out which specific application created the .pak archive and tell us about it.

Comment: I used 7zip for it

Comment: 7zip cannot produce .pak files, so I guess you extracted it using 7zip. There are many examples on how to handle zipped files in .NET, this question looks like it relates to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862291/how-to-set-picturebox-image-location-from-zip-without-extrat

Comment: 7zip can create .pak archives, I created it by clicking on image files and "add to archive" and I typed .pak and it works btw thanks for link

Comment: Notepad can create PAK files as well. The problem is: even if that file has a PAK extension, it's still not a PAK file. 7ZIP cannot create valid PAK files. It can create 7Z files which have a PAK extension, but that's a totally different thing.